# Cant find subpackage with tRPC and WebSockets

Tags: typescript, websocket, trpc

I'm trying to use the websockets provided with trpc for a live chat.
But when I follow the documentation and create the context as provided:

```
import {NodeHTTPCreateContextFnOptions} from "@trpc/server/dist/adapters/node-http";
import { IncomingMessage } from "http";
import ws from "ws";
export async function createContext(opts:
                                      | CreateExpressContextOptions
                                      | NodeHTTPCreateContextFnOptions<IncomingMessage, ws>) {
  const { req, res } = opts;
  const u = deserializeUser(<CreateExpressContextOptions>{ req, res });
  return createInnerTRPCContext({
    req: (await u).req,
    res: (await u).res,
    user: (await u).user,
  });
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './dist/adapters/ws' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\Schla\Documents\Semester 6\fwe-project\backend\node_modules@trpc\server\package.json

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?